# Questions on AND gates

Tags: logic-gates

I have been looking at AND gates and noticed there are a couple different ways to build them.  I am wonder when each of the circuits is better than the other:
[image]

or

[image]

Also with the first circuit I am a little confused about how it works.  If x and y are 5v then q3 will turn off.  Why is this?

Also, if X and Y are 0v what prevents the current from just flowing directly from the power source into Z making it 5v?

Comment: Why are you using BJT logic rather than CMOS?

Comment: None of the 2 you are showing. The first one has a week high level output. The second one has a week low level output. Both have static current. What is the third one?

Comment: *Which is better?* An SUV or a bicycle?  
Linux or Windows?  
Pen or pencil?

Comment: @Bort I guess a better question is in what situations would one be better than the other?

Comment: @TylerHilbert Do you have a specific context you're asking this in? If not, the question is probably far too broad.

Comment: @tangrs I guess I don't have a specific context.  I just wanted to understand what the difference between the 2 of them is.

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess I didn't consider using CMOS.  Is there any pros to using it over BJT?

Comment: @TylerHilbert Have you done any research on this? There's plenty of information online on CMOS logic gates. The tl;dr basics are faster switching times and lower static power consumption (among other advantages).

Comment: @TylerHilbert faster switching, far less power consumption, really high input impedance, very low output impedance, better noise margins...

Answer (score 1):

Really wide question and neither is really great.

Option A is better if you want to drive something low.. like pulling current down through an LED connected to 5v.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyhQSF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Option B is better for the converse if you want to supply current to some load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq01Jn.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, when X and Y are both on, there becomes a low-impedance path from the Q3 base resistor to ground. You can think of this as replacing Q1 and Q2 with a short to ground. Therefore, the base resistor is pulled low and Q3 is switched off.

When X and Y are off, current flows into the base of Q3 which switches it on. Again, this creates a low-impedance path to ground so Z must be at 0v.

As an aside, current will flow through R4 but it will drop 5V. Therefore, Z will still be at 0V.

Answer (score 0):

Option A is better because it has a chance of actually working.  With both Q1 and Q2 on, the base voltage of Q3 should be low enough to be off.  It could be fairly close, though.  it would be better if there was a voltage divider feeding the base of Q3.  That way the threshold voltage for turning on Q3 would be higher, which would give you more noise immunity.

Option B is just plain wrong if you are expecting the AND function.  Even with the top transistor off, the bottom can drive its emitter high just from the B-E diode action.  Therefore, when B is high, the output will be high, whether A is high or not.